# Erro ao importar o pandas no Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Eu não consigo importar o `pandas` no Jupyter Notebook. O erro apresenta essa mensagem:

> RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('c:\users\augus\analise_dados\lib\site-packages\numpy\**init**.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.
>
> See this issue for more information:
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html

Comment: Esse é um bug que ocorre em instalação do numpy 1.19.4 em maquinas rodando Windows independente da versão do Python 3.x 64bits. [Bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/wiki/FMod-Bug-on-Windows). A solução esta sugerida no link. Abraços!

Comment: Moi, bom dia! Conhece o [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)? Creio que irá facilitar sua vida. Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você instalou o Python recentemente, não foi? Esse é um erro de compatibilidade da versão 1.19.4 do numpy com o python3.9. O que você precisa fazer é um *downgrade* do seu numpy.

Abra um prompt do Windows e digite `pip uninstall numpy` depois `pip install numpy==1.19.3`. Se esse erro continuar acontecendo é provável que você tenha mais de uma distribuição do numpy em pastas diferentes.

Comment: Obrigado @Flavio. Eu fiz a instalação do pandas em um ambiente virtual, não tinha me atendado a versão.

Comment: Por algum motivo as atualização lançadas semana passada estão dando vários erros. O tensorflow tbm está dando problema com h5py e depois veio essa do numpy

Comment: @MoiTripa, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, por favor aceite ela e marque como útil. Obrigado